# Bucketing in Postgress

Tags: sql, postgresql

How should I bucket my data according to sales? If no sales fall under a particular bucket, then it should contain NA. The output must contain all buckets, also if they are empty. For bucket formation, no CASE or branching statements are used. Is it possible to do the bucketing with CTE's or Joins or with nesting? For example, the sample data is:

**Table1**

| id | sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 22 |
| 5 | 6 |

Output must be like this:

| bucket | id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-5 | 1 | 4 |
| 1-5 | 2 | 5 |
| 6-10 | 5 | 6 |
| 6-10 | 3 | 10 |
| 11-15 | NA | NA |
| 16-20 | NA | NA |
| 21-25 | 4 | 22 |

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Apologies sir. I am new to this platform and the language which I am using.

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the buckets and use a `left join`:

```
select b.name, t1.id, count(t1.id) as num_sales
from (select '1-5' as name, 1 as lo, 5 as hi union all
      select '6-10' as name, 6 as lo, 10 as hi union all
      select '11-15' as name, 11 as lo, 15 as hi union all
      select '16-20' as name, 16 as lo, 20 as hi union all
      select '21-25' as name, 21 as lo, 25 as hi
     ) b left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.sales >= b.lo and t1.sales <= b.hi
group by b.name, t1.id
order by min(lo);
```

The above should work in just about any database.  In Postgres, you can simplify it to:

```
select b.name, t1.id, count(t1.id) as num_sales
from (values ('1-5', 1, 5),
             ('6-10', 6, 10),
             ('11-15', 11, 15),
             ('16-20', 16, 20),
             ('21-25', 21, 25)
     ) b left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.sales >= b.lo and t1.sales <= b.hi
group by b.name, t1.id
order by min(lo);
```

If the bins are all the same size, you could also play tricks with `generate_series()`.

Comment: Hello sir, could you please give a solution for calculating buckets with a formula or an expression? Actually, the data in my system is too large as it can't be hardcoded like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE that returns the buckets and left join it to the table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(bucket) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT bucket + 5 FROM cte WHERE bucket < 20)
SELECT CONCAT(c.bucket, '-', c.bucket + 4) bucket, t1.id, t1.sales
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
ON t1.sales BETWEEN c.bucket AND c.bucket + 4
```

Or with `generate_series()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(g.bucket, '-', g.bucket + 4) bucket, t1.id, t1.sales
FROM generate_series(1, 25, 5) g(bucket) LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
ON t1.sales BETWEEN g.bucket AND g.bucket + 4
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bea4c04d68b393d6f46e7e99182c14de).
Results:

| bucket | id | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-5 | 1 | 4 |
| 1-5 | 2 | 5 |
| 6-10 | 3 | 10 |
| 6-10 | 5 | 6 |
| 11-15 | null | null |
| 16-20 | null | null |
| 21-25 | 4 | 22 |

Answer (score 0):

Another way by generating the buckets depending on max sales in the table :

```
with buckets as (
select t.b      as lowerBound,
       t.b + 4  as upperBound
from   generate_series(1, (select max(Sales) from Table1), 5) t(b)
)


select concat(lowerBound, '-', upperBound) as bucket, 
       t1.id, 
       t1.sales
from  buckets b
left join Table1 t1
on t1.sales between b.lowerBound and b.upperBound
```

[Demo db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a42ab8cfa1073b1d8d9279409449141b)